# Loading a file from filesystem in SPRING

Tags: spring, filepath

I have been strugling with this for a long while.

I am using an outer API and I need to pass file's path directly. I cannot modify it.

I looks like: functionmethod(String path);

So i cannot use Resource because I need to pass just path.

Is it possible in SPRING?

Comment: No. Just a file with some properties that I used to initilize new object.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use:

`(new File("")).getAbsolutePath()` that gives you the current path (application).

or (I think this one will fit better for you)

`getResource("fileName").getFile()`